# what is the correct way to add multi site option to CMS?

Tags: iis, content-management-system

we have already created a custom cms. now we have to provide multi site option to this.

i have initial idea that i have to create a default project which contain codebase that will be used to serve pages created from cms

for a single site it is currently supported , and even when we create manually another site then also it is working fine..

my question is what i m doing is really multisite ? ( we have one cms , but for every site we are creating separate application in IIS)
if yes, 
how would i able to create default application with certain folders,files in IIS programmatically or with some batch commands ..?

if no , 
can any one guide me on how to create multi site in cms by providing some tutorials on how multi site works in cms ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully follow your question, however, from what I do understand, you have a single code base, and you want to host multiple websites from the single code base, e.g. www.domain1.com, www.domain2.com, etc.

Well, if that is the case, you can very easily configure one IIS website to accept multiple hostnames to the same code base by setting up site bindings (see: http://www.orcsweb.com/blog/mark-newnam/how-to-set-up-site-bindings-in-internet-information-services-iis/).

As for your custom built CMS system, it will need to determine what the hostname is in order to display the correct website.

Comment: can u pls tell me the right way to add multi site option to CMS?

Comment: If I were developing this CMS I would add a new database table called Websites and for all my other tables I would amend them to make the primary key a composite key with the Website ID. Your database will then be setup for multiple sites and you could display a site from the database based on the incoming host name.